# Definite Integral for $\int_{0}^{a} x^{−n}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

Definite Integral for $\int_{0}^{a} x^{−n}dx$ where $n<=0$ and $0 < x < a$

$\int x^{−n}dx = x^{(-n + 1)}/(-n + 1)$. I'm not able to plug in the lower limit $0$ here because won't the result reaches $\infty$? I'm sure something is wrong with the thinking. If anyone can clarify it would be great.

Comment: If $n \leq 0$ the $-n+1>0$. So how do you get $\infty$?

Comment: It is strange to use *both* $-n$ and $n \leq 0$.  Together these imply that you are integrating a nonnegative power of $x$ (regardless of which variable is the variable of integration).

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, thanks. I overlooked that point. Now, I get $ x^{(-n + 1)} is 0 $ as x approaches 0

Comment: @EricTowers, I have corrected the question